# Returning variable vs. Setting variable

Tags: python, oop

I'm considering the following approaches for class initialisation:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.get_name()
    def get_name(self):
        return raw_input("Name: ")

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.get_name()
    def get_name(self):
        self.name = raw_input("Name: ")

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = raw_input("Name: ")
```

Is there any practical reason to opt for one over the others?

If not, which might be considered most Pythonic?

Comment: I wouldn't use a `raw_input()` inside an object though, but thats just me. Move it outside and supply the name when constructing your object.

Comment: Approach #2 is essentially the same as #1.

Comment: So basically you're asking what's the best way to design a class Foo? Well, I guess the most pythonic would be bar, although baz can make sense too, if not quux.

Comment: I should've gone for Spam. Nobody ever questions Spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If possible, `input()` the name outside of the class and pass it as a parameter to its `__init__()`.
- If this is not an option, I would go for the second alternative
- I would rename `get_name()` to something like `query_name()` or `input_name()`. `get_name()` sounds like a getter (that *gets* the value of `name`) not like a setter or a routine that *gets* data *from the user*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of doing a raw input in the constructor, but after all, why not...
I would prefer:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""

    def prompt_name(self):
        self.name = raw_input("Name: ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aFoo = Foo()
    aFoo.prompt_name()
```

Comment: Why not? Because application logic should be separated from getting  input. (If this is possible.)

Comment: `get_name` should return `name`, because it looks like a _getter_.

Comment: +1 soon, agree that the method name is not my primary choice... Fixed in edit :)